# Amazon S3 Invalid Argument Error Code

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file image to my Amazon s3 bucket but keep getting a 400 Bad request error. On digging i found the error code is Invalid Argument but I dont know why i keep getting the error.

controller.js

```
 Upload.upload({
              url: url,
              method: 'POST',
              fields : {
                key: imageURI.name,
                AWSAccessKeyId: key,
                acl: 'public-read',
                policy: policy,
                signature: signature, 
                "Content-Type": imageURI.type != '' ? imageURI.type : 'application/octet-stream',
                filename: imageURI.name
              },
              file: imageURI,
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(headers);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
```

cors configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8100</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://staging.com.my</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://partners.com.my</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This is the error report i get

```
  <Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required</Message>
    <ArgumentName> Authorization</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>YrRHhyr9uDF5SYntzyR3</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>94E78E47B15BE7C5</RequestId>
 <HostId>eR/Smasry6u1tE5b3DfrTLSGve3y4a/dZlYMLnBjcC2YhjUzskLzu3q85SYdfb9q0Ii09HCWcSI=</HostId>
    </Error>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please capture the response body and add it to the question.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added in the error report

Comment: @KingsleySimon did you get this fixed? What was the issue?

Comment: @Katana24 check the answer i jst posted

Answer (score 5):

@Katana24 try this. There is a possibility that in your headers, a value for Authorization is being sent so you have to delete that. Sometimes after doing so it will still give u an error so then u assign it to undefined. Hopefully this works for you and mark as answer if it does. Cheers

```
          Upload.upload({
            url: "https://partners-mobile-app.s3.amazonaws.com/", //S3 upload url including bucket name
            method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
             //Headers change here
              var headers = headersGetter();
              delete headers['Authorization'];
              return data;
            },
            headers: {
              'Authorization': undefined
            },
            fields : {
                key: imageURI.name,
                AWSAccessKeyId: key,
                acl: 'public-read',
                policy: policy,
                signature: signature, 
                "Content-Type": imageURI.type != '' ? imageURI.type : 'application/octet-stream',
                filename: imageURI.name
              },
              file: imageURI,
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(headers);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

          });
```

Comment: Did you also post this question on Github? I think i saw this same code there. No that didn't help me which suggests it's not a header issue. Thank's anyway

Answer (score 0):

CORS Configuration in S3 Amazon folder.

Please check and see what is being sent out in your headers to S3,
you are sending out "Content-Type" in your header. include that in cors configuration. check this sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```